# How can I use Isabelle in Emacs

Tags: emacs, isabelle

Most of the Isabelle documentation I see says that Proof-General supports Isabelle, but as far as I know PG dropped support about 5 years ago.

Is there another possibility to use (current) Isabelle with Emacs? Neither JEdit, nor VSCode really work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no official solution and no way to make Proof General work again.

> However, there is an unofficial solution. You could try [isabelle-emacs](https://github.com/m-fleury/isabelle-emacs/blob/Isabelle2021-more-vscode/src/Tools/emacs-lsp/spacemacs_layers/isabelle/README.org) (Disclaimer: I develop it in my free time. The experience is a bit rough, but there are a few people using it). It uses the Isabelle's LSP server like VScode, but it uses Emacs based.
>  The difference between isabelle-emacs and Isabelle is limited to a few line in the LSP server and the Emacs specific code. Neither kernel nor any other theory is changed.

Comment: Great, looks like exactly what I'm looking for. I will see how well your package works for me